Symbolic link for pub package development
Is there a way to create a symbolic link to use when developing pub.dev packages so that I can test my package locally before deploying it. I way to link it to my local test apps.
Similar to npm link in npm.
I am trying to test a pub package locally.

Just have your project that consumes your test package use a "path:" spec in the pubspec.yaml to point at your package.
